# Flexslider only showing to logged in users

Tags: 7, users, javascript

My flexslider is only showing to logged in users. I'm using a view in a block and I've checked that the block is showing for all user roles.
The View "Access" permissions are set to anyone that can view published content. Changing the Access value to "none" didn't seem to make any difference. The admin user still sees it, but anonymous users don't... Any suggestions ?
[image]

Comment: does the content show for anonymous users, just not in the form you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a decent answer I'm afraid folks, but it turned out to be a conflict with the "Taxonomy Term Status" module.

The Flexslider was showing taxonomy terms, but when the term status module was turned on (which allows taxonomy terms to be "unpublished") The whole slider stopped being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with Flexslider.

After checking all the permissions issues, I remembered that the content for my slides was "unpublished". I switched it to "Published" and, VOILA! It worked.

It's a common practice to have the slides "unpublished", so I don't know why this makes a difference, but it did.